# c# check if string is set and use its value

Tags: c#, html, css

I have a string that can contain a value for a background color. If it is set then I want to take the value of the string and place it inline in the css class, otherwise the default fallback value should be `bg-white`.

In C# I have tried the following:

```
<div class="py-0 px-1 mt-0 @(Model.PlatformBackgroundColor ? Model.PlatformBackgroundColor : "bg-white") text-center trial-teaser-platform-rounded">
    @Html.PropertyFor(m => m.TrialTeaserData.Platform.Platform)
</div>
```

The error I am getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PlatformBackgroundColor) ? "bg-white": ....` ? or just `Model.PlatformBackgroundColor == null ? "bg-white":... `

Comment: Could be as simple as `Model.PlatformBackgroundColor ?? "bg-white"`. See [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: Another option is to define bg-white as the default color in your CSS, then override it with the PlatformBackgroundColor. If it's empty then the default color will remain in force.

Comment: @JohnWu: until no one assigns `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to John Wu. I ended up using this suggestion which I found to be very concise and elegant for this use case:

```
Model.PlatformBackgroundColor ?? "bg-white"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PlatformBackgroundColor ) ? Model.PlatformBackgroundColor : "bg-white")
```